# Resistance-capacitance (RC) circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, capacitance, batteries

[image]

My textbook says: *"This continues until the voltage across the capacitor matches the emf of the battery"*

If I were to have a resistor in series with a capacitor, would the voltage across the capacitor still be equal to the emf of the battery?

My thinking process: The voltage across the capacitor will not be the same due to [KVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_voltage_law) as there would be a voltage drop across the resistor as well.

Comment: Could you add the context just in front of the quote? What continues? Also, in your picture, you do have a resistor in series with a capactor. So what is the situation that the quote refers to?

Comment: How is this not a duplicate?

Comment: @PeterMortensen This answer, by Alfred Centauri, is the closest I can find here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/340124/313612. It gives the capacitor voltage vs. time equation. Alfred Centauri also answered below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There will be a voltage drop across the resistor only when current flows. When the capacitor gets charged to equal the battery voltage the current stops and there is no longer a voltage drop across the resistor.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wait so just to confirm, the voltage across a capacitor will always be equal to the emf of a battery?

Comment: (+1) If the capacitor is initially not charged, its voltage will be zero. Assume the switch then closes. The initial current is the emf divided by the resistance. The current exponentially declines to zero as time passes. The steady state is that the capacitor is charged to the battery’s emf and the voltage across the resistor is zero: no current flows.

Comment: @michael No, only if it is charged so that the voltage across its plates is the same as the battery emf.

Comment: @EdV so the final voltage once the capacitor has fully charged would be equal to the battery's emf?

Comment: Yes. Assume the capacitor voltage at time t is V(t) and the switch closes at t=0. Before t=0, assume the capacitor is uncharged, so V(t)=0. At t=0, the switch closes and the capacitor starts charging at its maximum rate. But as it charges, the current into it decreases because the voltage drop across the resistor decreases. So the capacitor voltage, as a function of time, is V(t) = V times [1 - exp(-t/RC)] where V is just the battery’s emf. As t goes to infinity, the exponential goes to zero, so V(t) goes to V. See [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/478939/223146).

Answer (score 7):

> My question: If I were to have a resistor in series with a capacitor,
> would the voltage across the capacitor still be equal to the emf of
> the battery?

In an ideal circuit theory context, the answer is *no* except in the trivial case that the initial condition is just that.

That is, for the ideal RC circuit drawn, the voltage across the capacitor asymptotically approaches $V$, the voltage across the voltage source, if the initial condition is otherwise.

As Bob D very correctly points out, the voltage across the resistor is zero unless there is a non-zero current through. However, in the ideal case, the current through goes to zero only at $t=\infty$, i.e., the capacitor never stops charging.

Practically, however, and for the zero capacitor voltage initial condition, the capacitor is considered 'fully charged' after $t=5\cdot\tau= 5\cdot RC$ seconds.

Answer (score 1):

If you set up a circuit like this, with reasonably high values for the resistor and the capacitor, a measurable current will flow for at least a few seconds. Initially the current is quite high, but as the charge and voltage on the capacitor increase, the voltage across the resistor decreases and so the current decreases. After a time the current will have dropped to a value which is too small to measure, and the voltages across the battery and capacitor will be equal within the limits of measurement.